# Find cumulative sum of values at a point in flow chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a process that can be represented by this flow:

[image]

Each "M" point adds its own value to the flow and transfers cumulative values from point to point.  The points, values, and flows are described in this table:

[image: current]

What I would like to know is how to sum up the values at each point, but I am getting these incorrect results:

[image: results]

**`C2=B2, C3=B3+C2, C4=B4+C7+C3, C5=B5+C4, C6=B6+C5, C7=B7+C8, C8=B8`**

The results should be:

**`C2=1, C3=3, C4=8, C5=12, C6=14, C7=2, C8=1`**

I have tried this function at **C2**

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,F:F,0)),C:C))+B2`

This works fine, until I get to **C4**, where I get 6, but the value should be 8. There are values from point M2 and M3.1 going to M3 (**C4**)

Hope you can help me?

Comment: I don't understand. Is the "point" mean the nth next values, not including its own? The bottom of the chart isn't making any sense to me

Comment: Your logic is wrong. The selected box, C4 (in the second picture) shows a value of 6, but summing from M3 to M4 is 7, not 6 as shown or 8 as you wrote it should be.

Comment: @Dave I can only guess points M3.1 and M3.2 are meant to be in between M3 and M4. That is the only way I could get 8 as described.

Comment: To everyone confused by the request, the flow chart at the bottom is the best account of what is needed. The user wants the sum of everything that flows into a given node. All the flow relations are described pairwise in columns E and F. In my opinion, this is an interesting, challenging problem.

Comment: @Excellll if that flowchart is the case, would the table need to be in a different order?

Comment: In that case, I'd vote for VBa but OP states worksheet-function :(

Comment: @Dave I put [worksheet-function] there because it seemed like the OP was after that kind of solution, based on what had been tried. I removed the tag.

Comment: Sorry @Excellll didn't realise you changed that . Will look into tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Excellll](https://superuser.com/users/76571/excellll) and [fixer1234](https://superuser.com/users/364367/fixer1234) for making it clearer.

OP's proposed formula is fine then, it just needs to be tuned:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,F:F,0)),C:C))+B2
+IF(MID(A2,3,1)<>".",SUMPRODUCT((A:A>A2)*(A:A<"M"&MID(A2,2,1)+1),B:B),0)
```

If you've got a period in node name, formula is just fine; otherwise you add values corresponding to node names greater than current (eg. "M3") and less than next (eg. "M(3+1)", that's what `&MID()+1` does)